# Opensearch reindex takes twice to complete

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have an index in my Opensearch domain called `shakespeare`. The index has 4998 documents:

```
GET /shakespeare/_count
{
  "count" : 4998,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

Now, I want to reindex this index to another index. For some reason, the first reindex operation only reindexes a subset of the documents:

```
PUT new_index

POST _reindex
{
   "source":{
      "index":"shakespeare"
   },
   "dest":{
      "index":"new_index"
   }
}

# result
{
  "took" : 309,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 4998,
  "updated" : 0,
  "created" : 999,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 1,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [
    {
      "index" : "new_index",
      "id" : "29",
      "cause" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "mapper [speech_number] cannot be changed from type [text] to [long]"
      },
      "status" : 400
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that it created 999 documents (it's consistently around this number - 998, 999, 997).

Then, if I run the reindex operation again, the rest of the documents will be reindexed:

```
# same operation, result:
{
  "took" : 855,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 4998,
  "updated" : 999,
  "created" : 3999,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 5,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

Any idea why is that?

Comment: You can see from your first run that you get an error `mapper [speech_number] cannot be changed from type [text] to [long]` which is why the reindex process stops. You need to check what's wrong with document with id 29

Comment: @Val, thanks, I completely missed this. From what I can see, the values in `speech_number` in this document is no different than any other. Do you know exactly what this error message mean?

Comment: @Val, additionally, when I run the second time, it does succeed, so what gives?

Comment: It means that the mapping of `new_index` contains `speech_number` as `text` and document 27 contains a `long` value instead. To make sure you should create `new_index` with the same mapping as the `shakespeare` source index before running the reindex.